# Find pdf file with input form

Tags: php, forms, pdf, input, download

I want my client to be able to download their invoice from my website.

If you have better suggestion, feel free to let me know.

I want 2 input fields. Postal code and phone number then a submit button that will go retrieve the PDF file matching the input.

```
<form action="#" method="post" name="Facture" class="bodytext" id="Facture">
<input name="postal" type="text" id="postal" onclick="this.value=''" value="Code Postal | H1H 1H1" size="26" /><br />
<input name="telephone" type="text" id="telephone" onclick="this.value=''" value="Téléphone | 000-000-0000" size="26" /><br />
<input class="submit" type="submit" name="envoyer" id="envoyer" value="Chercher" />
</form>
```

All invoices will be in a folder, let's say /invoices and file name will be `H1H1H10000000000.pdf`.

I want the submit button to download the file corresponding to input fields joint together.

This is what I planned but if you have a better idea to help me, all I want is my client to be able to print/download their PDF invoice and try to make sure it still private and secure.

Comment: I would suggest using something a bit more secure then what you are suggested. Does your website require the user to login? Perhaps have a look at: https://php.net/manual/en/features.http-auth.php

Comment: @Malachi I don't use login on my website and it's not something my client will want to work with. Something really quick to retrieve a pdf file according to input value. It's only invoices so security doesn't need to be too crazy since the only thing here will be a name and a price on the pdf...

Comment: Okays - If security isn't an issue then your proposed solution sounds like an alright approach. But your question you said "private and secure"